# Bank statements, income tax return, Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, indian-citizens, paperwork

I am an Indian citizen, I have got an invitation for a job interview in Germany, so I would require  a Schengen Visa and I am applying under tourist category.

The company inviting me for interview is sponsoring cost of travel and stay. I have a few questions regarding [required documents](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/NewDelhi_NorthIndia/tourist_visit_docreq.html):

1. Proof of financial status: Do I still need to provide bank statements and income tax return form. In case I have to, can I show bank statements from a bank in another country where I worked previously.
2. Civil status: Do all documents need to be in english. My marriage certificate is in Hindi, is it required to submit this too, though my wife is not traveling with me.

Comment: I think that a job interview is an invalid purpose for a tourist visa.  The company interviewing you should send you an invitation and you should get a business visa.  Not only would this increase the chance that the visa will be granted, but it would also be easier and possibly quicker(depending on the embassy/consulate in your area, of course).

Comment: There is no "business visa" or "tourist visa" in Schengen though of course you should state your real intention and tick all boxes accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I did, these two kinds of documents are mentioned in both tourist and business category visas

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply through your local German embassy or consulate for a business visa with an invitation from the potential employer or a 'job seeker' visa (if available), in both cases you will be given temporary residence in Germany for a period of up to 6 months. Documents typically need to be translated to German and signed by an authority.